# Google Maps Javascript API V3 : Search Requests

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

When calling search service api

```
var pyrmont = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8665433,151.1956316);
var request = { location: pyrmont, radius: '500', types: ['store'] };
service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
service.search(request, callback);
```

1. is it necessary to give the location/radius of the search area?
2. What about if i want to search a location in total world not in specified area like google does at http://maps.google.com/.

**--- UPDATE ---**

This is my updated code as @Trott advised but i am getting status = "ZERO_RESULTS" in my callback function.

```
var keyword='search placename';
var request = { name : keyword,
bounds : new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
google.maps.LatLng(-89.999999,-179.999999),
google.maps.LatLng(89.999999,179.999999)
)};
service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
service.search(request, callback);

function callback(results, status)
{
    console.log("status="+status);
    if ( status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++)
        console.log(results[i]); 
    }
}
```

What i am doing wrong?

Comment: On the go right now, but really quickly:  I strongly suspect that a Google Places search for "search placename" will come up empty, especially considering how sparse the Google Places database is at the current time.  Try searching for "museum" and see if that gets any results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Calls to `search()` must contain either a location and a radius, or else a bounds (as a LatLngBounds object).  This is documented at http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/places.html#place_search_requests.
2. You could see what happens if you specify a LatLngBnds that covers the entire world.  Haven't tried it, but if it worked, that should have the effect of searching the whole world without necessarily biasing a particular location.

LatLngBounds is documented at http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#LatLngBounds.  I think you'd want to do something like this:

```
var sw = new google.maps.LatLng(-89.999999,-179.999999);
var ne = new google.maps.LatLng(89.999999,179.999999);
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(sw,ne);
```

Comment: Thanks @Trott for your response, i got your 2 point but sorry to say that don't have enough knowledge about LatLong to compose that bounds which will cover all the world. Can you do it for me. Thanks.

Comment: OK, I added code that I **think** should create a bounds that covers (almost) the entire world.

Comment: Thanks i will try this code and let you know if it works or not.