# I can't get the Google's Places Service's output

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

In my code, first, I am trying to find the user's location by GeoLocation service on the Google Maps.

Second, I am trying to show 'Bars', like places you go to drink alcohol, with the Google's Places Service near users location. It should put markers on 'Bars' near users location.

However this doesn't work, I am encountering a problem. But I don't know what it is. It opens the map without 'Bars' near my location.

My css code:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
}

@media print {
  html, body {
    height: auto;
  }



  #map_canvas {
    height: 650px;
  }
}
```

This is my javascript and my HTML code=

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Map Geolocation</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="mapcss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!--
    Include the maps javascript with sensor=true because this code is using a
    sensor (a GPS locator) to determine the user's location.
    See: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html#SpecifyingSensor
    -->
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var map;

      function initialize() {
        var myOptions = {
          zoom: 6,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
            myOptions);

        // Try HTML5 geolocation
        if(navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                                             position.coords.longitude);

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
              map: map,
              position: pos,
              content: 'Location found using HTML5.'
            });

            map.setCenter(pos);

            var request = {
                location: pos,
                radius: 500,
                types: ['bar']
            };

            infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
            service.search(request, callback);

          },

      function() {
            handleNoGeolocation(true);
          });
        } else {
          // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
          handleNoGeolocation(false);
        }
      }

      function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
        if (errorFlag) {
          var content = 'Error: The Geolocation service failed.';
        } else {
          var content = 'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.';
        }

        var options = {
          map: map,
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(45.4643898,9.1883469),
          content: content
        };

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(options);
        map.setCenter(options.position);
      }
      function callback(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
          for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            createMarker(results[i]);
          }
        }
      }

      function createMarker(place) {
        var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: place.geometry.location
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
          infowindow.setContent(place.name);
          infowindow.open(map, this);
        });
      }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You really need to accept those correct answers to your previous questions.

Comment: ok I accept that's why I correct and redo it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Google Places search can often come up empty, especially considering how sparse the Google Places database is at the current time (or was the last time I tried it). See [Google Maps Javascript API V3 : Search Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6265443/google-maps-javascript-api-v3-search-requests) for some extra details and suggestions.